# How unmask entry password inside the user control in the first click Xamarin.Form

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I created an user control containing an entry and an image.

**PROBLEM**

The password unmask starts to work after two clicks.

Initially this is so:

[image]

**First click:** Only changes the icon

[image]

**Second click:** Change the font and icon
[image]

After the second click it works correctly

**IMPLEMENTATION**

**User control**

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
         xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Projecro_3.ControlCostumiado"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"     
         Padding="10"
         x:Class="Projecro_3.Controls.EntryControl">

 <AbsoluteLayout>

           <control:CustomEntry x:Name="entry">  </control:CustomEntry>             
            <Image x:Name="imgFinal" >
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                     Tapped="ImagemFinal_Tapped"
                     NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
</AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Class:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class EntryControl : ContentView
{
    public bool IsPassword
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(IsPasswordProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsPasswordProperty, value); 
        }

    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty IsPasswordProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                 propertyName: "IsPassword",
                                                 returnType: typeof(bool),
                                                 declaringType: typeof(EntryControl),
                                                 defaultValue: false,
                                                 defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                 propertyChanged: IsPasswordPropertyChanged);

    public EntryControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        entry.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private static void IsPasswordPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (EntryControl)bindable;
        if (control == null) return;

        bool isPassword = (bool)newValue;
        control.entry.IsPassword = isPassword;
        control.imgFinal.Source = new FileImageSource { File = isPassword ? imageEyePassaword : imageEyeOffPassaword };
    }

    private void ImagemFinal_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsPassword = !IsPassword; 
    }
    private const string imageEyePassaword = "eye.png";
    private const string imageEyeOffPassaword = "eye_off.png";
}
```

**MainPage**

```
 <control:EntryControl IsPassword="True"></control:EntryControl>
```

Comment: Hi, after testing shared code, not finding problem in my project.The only different in my code is `<control:CustomEntry x:Name="entry">  </control:CustomEntry> ` is a stanard Entry `<Entry x:Name="entry">  </Entry>` .https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oj6a.gif

Comment: The problem was in the entry I customized

Comment: Great, glad to you have find the reason.If solved it, remember to share in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in the  `<control:CustomEntry x:Name="entry"> </control:CustomEntry>`, `CustomEntry` it's an entry that I've customized.

```
 public class CustomEntry : Entry
 { 

 }
```

**Android**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace Projecro_3.Droid
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                gd.SetColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                this.Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
                this.Control.SetRawInputType(InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions);                  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

I just removed this line

```
this.Control.SetRawInputType(InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions)
```